# Which of Ash's Pokemon faints the most?

Tags: pokemon

In the Pokémon anime, which one of Ash's Pokémon (other than the Pokémon that have been in more than one region with Ash, unless you re-count the number of faints for each region, and not including Raticate or Aipom or any of his unofficial Pokémon) has fainted the most?

Comment: Oh i just realized. Do you mean pokemon that have been in one more region than ash or one more region WITH ash?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to bother checking every single episode, since I have better things to do with my life.

However, I can say with a 90% certainty that it's Pikachu. Not because it's weak, but because he has stayed with Ash the whole time, much more longer than any other of Ash's pokemon. So he's battled more and likely to have lost more.

Answer (score -1):

I am 100% sure that it is torrterra or torkoal. but I think it is torkoal because when torrterra was a turtwig, he won a lot more times while torkoal barely wins.

Comment: What makes you 100% sure of your claim?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).